# accessing objects in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

```js
const lineExampleOne = 
  [ { weight: 150, floor: 2 } 
  , { weight: 200, floor: 3 } 
  , { weight: 120, floor: 5 } 
  , { weight:  80, floor: 2 } 
  , { weight: 180, floor: 4 } 
  , { weight: 170, floor: 4 } 
  ];

let newArray = [];

lineExampleOne.forEach((person)=>{
  newArray.push(person);
})

console.log(newArray);
```

The console returns something like this `[object Object],[object Object]` etc...

How do I correctly add each object to my empty newArray?
How do I properly access each objects properties from my newArray?
and is there a way to test how many unique values I have for floors and weight of all the objects in my newArray ?

Comment: what you are doing is creating a new array which in the end looks same as your lineExampleOne

Comment: yu have to turn the arrow on you browser console (in front of each object)... ?

Comment: to keep track of unique weights and floors. you can initialize two Sets and inside the foreach add floor/weight to the respective set.

Answer (score 0):

> The console returns something like this [object Object],[object Object] etc...

That's just how the console logs objects. If you want more insight when logging collections like this I suggest using `console.table(newArray)`.

> How do I correctly add each object to my empty newArray?

Your code looks correct. Could be more succinct using `map` if interested (since `map` returns a new array). E.g. `const newArray = lineExampleOne.map((a) => a);`

> How do I properly access each objects properties from my newArray?

You'll need to use `find`. E.g. `const item = newArray.find(({ weight }) => weight === 200); console.log(item.weight)`. `find` will return the *first* match. If you want all matches then you'll want to use `filter`.

> is there a way to test how many unique values I have for floors and weight of all the objects in my newArray.

Yes. `Set` will dedupe arrays, so you can use it for properties on a collection like so.

```
const distinctWeights = [...new Set(newArray.map((a) => a.weight))];
console.log(distinctWeights.length);
```